# Scheme procedure

Tags: scheme

I am trying to create a Scheme function.

I created this piece of code but I keep getting errors:

```
(define (slope-of-line p1 p2)
  (let ((m (/ (- (cdr p2) (cdr p1))
               (- (car p2) (car p1))))
         (b (- (cdr p1)
               (* m (car p1)))))
    (lambda (x) (+ (* m x) b))))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It seems ok, but I notice you are trying to use `m` in the expression of the binding `b`. At the time of that expression `m` doesn't exist. If you wonder why you can translate the let into a anonymous function call it is syntax sugar for:

```
((lambda (m b)
   (lambda (x) (+ (* m x) b)))
 (/ (- (cdr p2) (cdr p1)) (- (car p2) (car p1)))
 (- (cdr p1) (* m (car p1))))
```

Here you clearly see that `m` is used outside of the lambda that defines it.
Your code can be fixed by replacing `let` with `let*`.

```
(define (slope-of-line p1 p2)
  (let* ((m (/ (- (cdr p2) (cdr p1))
               (- (car p2) (car p1))))
         (b (- (cdr p1)
               (* m (car p1)))))
    (lambda (x) (+ (* m x) b))))

(define slope (slope-of-line '(1 . 3) '(6 . 4)))
(slope 20) ; ==> 34/5 (which is close to ~6,8)
```

The reason why this works is because `let*` is just syntax sugar for nested `let`:

```
(let* ((a a-expression)
       (b b-expression))
  body ...)
```

Is the same as:

```
(let ((a a-expression))
  (let ((b b-expression))
    body ...))
```

Comment: @Annabelle What do you mean by "this piece"? Did you mean you added the single `*` and you still got errors? Every block in my answer except for the second one contains either your original error or pseudocode that will end as undefined identifiers.

Comment: @Annabelle so instead of replacing `let` with `let*` you nested the `let`. OK. Both works just fine. What kind of error do you get? If you then try to call it as `(slope-of-line '(1 . 3) '(6 . 4))` it returns a procedure. Thus if you assign it to a name eg. `(define slope (slope-of-line '(1 . 3) '(6 . 4)))` you can then call it with x values to get y `(slope 20) ; ==> 34/5`. Seems just fine to me

Comment: @Annabelle You are asking how to replace `(lambda (x) ...)` with `m` in your code? Well just do that. You don't need `let` at all.